# running a loop per rank in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I want each rank runs over a loop and do several stuff in the loop, this loop is important to me because based on the loop I will go through a vector and each rank needs to do different things based on the vector.
the simple code should be :

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // MPI Start
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int pCurrentID, pRightID, pLeftID, tag = 1 , size, value;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pCurrentID);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  while (c == false ) {
  // do some stuff   
     for (int J=0; J<2; J++) {

       std::cout<<"rank "<<pCurrentID<<" J "<<J<<std::endl;
     }
   // do some stuff and calculate C
  }

  /* All done */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

the size of vector when I am printing it, is 2. but I got the following result for cost:

```
rank 2 J 0
rank 0 J 0
rank 1 J 0
rank 0 J 0
rank 2 J 0
rank 1 J 0
```

why each rank is not going through the loop? I did the same thing with while loop and got the same result.

Comment: There is no vector in you code.

Comment: Hi @Jodocus I made the code easy because the problem was with the indexes and not looping over the ranks

Comment: The code does not compile (`c` is undefined). I fixed it locally and it produced the expected result. Please show the code you used and the result with the exact same code.